# Cannot figure out which two objects are attached to different ObjectContext objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, caching

So I recently took a system (MVC/Entity Framework) that we have and added in a bunch of Cached Repositories to speed it up. It seemed to work fine in testing, however when we pushed it out we have been randomly getting this error from random users:

```
Exception Message: The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

Stack Trace: at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.ValidateContextsAreCompatible(RelatedEnd targetRelatedEnd) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Add(IEntityWrapper wrappedTarget, Boolean applyConstraints, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean allowModifyingOtherEndOfRelationship, Boolean forceForeignKeyChanges) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PerformAdd(IEntityWrapper wrappedOwner, RelatedEnd relatedEnd, IEntityWrapper entityToAdd, Boolean isForeignKeyChange) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.PerformAdd(IList`1 entries) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.DetectChanges(Boolean force) at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetStateEntries(Func`2 predicate) at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbChangeTracker.Entries() at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() at ClinicalCMS.Domain.CMSContext.SaveChanges() in C:\Projects\BeaconEDC\ClinicalCMS.Domain\CMSContext.cs:line 255 at BeaconEDC.Areas.DataEntry.Controllers.EngineController.MarkComplete(Int64 studyId, Int64 subjectId, Int64 formIteration, StudyAssignment assignment, String caseId, StudyForm studyForm) in C:\Projects\BeaconEDC\BeaconEDC\Areas\DataEntry\Controllers\EngineController.cs:line 375 at BeaconEDC.Areas.DataEntry.Controllers.EngineController.Edit(Int64 studyId, Int64 subjectId, Int64 formIteration, Int64 studyFormId, FormCollection collection) in C:\Projects\BeaconEDC\BeaconEDC\Areas\DataEntry\Controllers\EngineController.cs:line 312 at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_2.b__2() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__4() at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

Now, I write to the database in lots of places, but it always reports this in the same place. But there is nothing I'm seeing in that part of the code that use anything from any of the cached repositories. I literally just create a new object, add a bunch of stuff to it (that are either strings, longs, integers, or dates), add it to the context, and save changes.

To make things more frustrating, I've never been able to reproduce this in Visual Studio. Only occurs on the server.

So my question is, is there any way of getting more information out of that exception? Some way of telling exactly what two objects it is talking about?

Here is the bit where it is failing:

```
HatterasGlobal global = repo.HatterasGlobal(iid, caseId, "FormStatus");
if (global == null)
{
    global = new HatterasGlobal();
    global.CaseID = caseId;
    global.GlobalName = "FormStatus";
    global.Mode = 1;
    global.Value = "C";
    global.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    global.HatterasInstrumentID = iid;
    global.StudyId = studyId;
    global.SubjectId = subjectId;
    global.FormIteration = formIteration;

    repo.Add(global);
}
else
{
    global.Value = "C";
    global.Modified = DateTime.Now;

    repo.SaveChanges();
}

// set the date complete
HatterasGlobal dateGlobal = repo.HatterasGlobal(studyForm.Form.IID, caseId, "DateComplete");
if (dateGlobal == null)
{
    dateGlobal = new HatterasGlobal();
    dateGlobal.CaseID = caseId;
    dateGlobal.GlobalName = "DateComplete";
    dateGlobal.Mode = 1;
    dateGlobal.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    dateGlobal.Modified = DateTime.Now;
    dateGlobal.HatterasInstrumentID = iid;
    dateGlobal.StudyId = studyId;
    dateGlobal.SubjectId = subjectId;
    dateGlobal.FormIteration = formIteration;

    repo.Add(dateGlobal);
}
else
{
    dateGlobal.Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    dateGlobal.Modified = DateTime.Now;

    repo.SaveChanges();
}
```

The line that it is actually bombing on in the stack trace is this guy:

```
HatterasGlobal dateGlobal = repo.HatterasGlobal(studyForm.Form.IID, caseId, "DateComplete");
```

But I suspect it is having a problem with repo.Add(global). All that does is this:

```
public void Add(HatterasGlobal global)
{
    _context.HatterasGlobals.Add(global);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Here is where the Context is registered (Unity):

```
container.RegisterType<CMSContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
...
container.RegisterType<IDataEntryRepository, CachedDataEntryRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(typeof(CMSContext)));
```

Inside the repo, the context is initialized like so:

```
protected CMSContext _context;
public EFDataEntryRepository(CMSContext context)
{
   this._context = context;
}
```

(The EFDataEntryRepository is the base class for CachedDataEntryRepository.)

Here is an example of how I'm doing the caching:

```
public override Study Study(long id)
        {
            var study = HttpRuntime.Cache["Study-" + id + "-" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name] as Study;
            if (study == null)
            {
                lock (CacheLockObject)
                {
                    study = HttpRuntime.Cache["Study-" + id + "-" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name] as Study;
                    if (study == null)
                    {
                        study = base.Study(id);
                        if (study != null) HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Study-" + id + "-" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, study, null, _absolute, _sliding);
                    }
                }
            }

            return study;
        }
```

Does that help?

Comment: What's the code like where this is thrown? I don't think it's related to your cached repositories, it looks like you're mixing contexts

Comment: You'll have to include some code. With new entites, "add a bunch of stuff to it (that are either strings, longs, integers, or dates)" won't cause this error.

Comment: Hey sorry guys, let me see what code I can inject up there. I'm using Unity to inject the context, so it should all be from the same context.

Answer (score 0):

"at ClinicalCMS.Domain.CMSContext.SaveChanges() ..."  You need to dive further down the exception stack past the "...", that will be the meat of the problem.

The usual culprit for this will be code that is passing entities around. As a simple example:

```
public IEnumerable<RelatedEntity> LoadRelated()
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        return context.RelatedEntities.ToList();
    }
}

public void SaveEntity(ParentEntity entity)
{
    using (var context = new MyDbContext())
    {
        context.ParentEntities.Add(entity);
        context.SaveChanges()
    }
}

public void SomeAction(ParentEntityViewModel viewModel)
{
    var relatedEntities = LoadRelated();
    var relatedEntity = relatedEntities
        .OrderBy(x => x.ApplicableDate)
        .First(x => x.ApplicableDate >= DateTime.Now);
    var newEntity = new ParentEntity
    {
        Name = viewModel.Name,
        RelatedEntity = relatedEntity
     };
     SaveEntity(newEntity);
}
```

... again, a bare-bones example for demonstration. This normally manifests when code is using things like Repository patterns which are either leveraging different bounded contexts (i.e. different DbContexts that load the same entities) or where the DbContext in question has multiple instances declared such as a different lifetime scope depending on whether you use an IoC Container or not.

The above example is using 2 different instances of a DbContext. The related entities were loaded in the first, but the Save uses a second. When we create a parent entity and associate an entity still tracked by the first and then give it to the second, we would get that error you are seeing.

Given you are seeing the error in production but not in testing I would suspect one of two things:

1. This is a rare scenario that users are tripping that you aren't reproducing when testing.
2. This is a concurrent session issue and your caching is doing something naughty.

I'm leaning towards #2 given caching and entities are never something that should really ever be done. If your DbContext is scoped per-request via an EF context, and you are loading entities then throwing them into a static cache, while that request is active, *other* requests which will spawn other DbContexts might pick out entities from a cache. These entities would be associated with the other request's DbContext and would likely result in errors like what you are seeing.  Any caching you do should only ever be done at a session state, not static / cross-session.

Comment: I understand... though I made sure not to use other entities when writing the problematic records to the database. I make reference to them by ID only. I figure my caching is doing something bad, I just can't figure out what!

Comment: Can you add the code for where the "repo" instance is declared so that we can see what you mean by a "cached" repository. The Add method is not caching the entities as I was suspecting, so it looks like the repository itself (and it's context) could be cached/global. Also, how is the DbContext declared/initialized inside the Repos?

Comment: Added. Also added the full stack trace. As far as CachedRepository, I'm not caching the whole repository... just certain objects that are accessed a lot. And that doesn't include the objects being written above.

Comment: Ok thanks.. I still don't see what this "caching" implementation consists of. What does "CachedDataEntryRepository" do that the base repository does not? The repository context is scoped to the request which is fine, but depending on what "caching" you are doing I suspect entity references are being cached against undisposed contexts.  Lastly, what is "formIteration"? Is it a string or an entity?

Comment: FormIteration is a long. I'll put an example of a cached bit above. Basically I did something like this: https://ardalis.com/introducing-the-cachedrepository-pattern

Comment: So the caching is caching entities. I don't exactly see how that ties into the repository, but if the repository is caching an entity that was loaded once by a DbContext by one request, if the next request can pull an entity from the cache that will be bad news. The cache is set up to cache per user, but do you guard against users operating more than one tab in the browser?  Either way, caching entities is ok for read operations, provided the risk of stale data is acceptable, but you cannot rely on it for updates.

Comment: I'm really not seeing where in my code it could be referencing another entity in that chunk of code. I'm back to thinking there must be another entity that is trying to save when I'm doing the SaveChanges. Is there any way of getting the entities being added that are causing this error?

Comment: You can access modified entities by using the `dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries.Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Added).Select(x => x.Entity).ToList();` That will be a list of `Object` of all known modified or added entities. Based on the information I see a potential issue where requests for the same user are being made and entities in one request are potentially accessing entities from another request. If you are facing performance issues I would look at options other than caching to address that. Caching details from entities = Ok. Caching entities = Bad.